# Getting thumbnail for trimmed video in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

Here is my code:
When I try to do this 
`self.my.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "\(self.sharedelegate.editthumbforvideo)")`,
the value of `self.my.image` is always printing nil.`self.videodelegate.editthumbforvideo` datatype is `(UIImage)` and `my.image` is `(UIImageview)`.

Don't know how to overcome this issue and can't get thumbnail image of trimmed video.

Thanks in Advance

```
            let url=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath as String)
            let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: url)
            let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset);
            imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

            let timestamp = CMTime(seconds: 0.0, preferredTimescale:        60)
            var actualTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
            let myImage = try?( imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(timestamp, actualTime: &actualTime))
            self.image=UIImage(CGImage: myImage!)
            print("my print...\(self.image)")
            self.videodelegate.editthumbforvideo = self.image
            self.my.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "\(self.sharedelegate.editthumbforvideo)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create thumbnail by writing below code,

```
var err: NSError? = nil
let url=NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath as String)
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
let cgImage = imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil, error: &err)

let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got thumbnail Image but dont know how to display that in Imageview

Comment: Write like : self.my.image = uiImage OR self.my.image = UIImageView(image: uiImage)